# dot-dot-dot argument does not work as expected

Tags: r, function, arguments

I use the following function to create a bunch of normally distributed data according to some convariance/correlation matrix `Sigma`.

```r
fun <- function(.sample_size, .Sigma, .ndraws = 1, ...) {
  replicate(.ndraws,
            scale(MASS::mvrnorm(.sample_size, mu = rep(0, ncol(.Sigma)), Sigma = .Sigma)),
            simplify = FALSE)
}

Sigma <- matrix(c(1, 0.3, 0.3, 1), nrow = 2)
```

The function `mvrnorm` has an additional argument `empirical` which can be set to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. I added the `...` agrument in my function `fun` to be able to pass the argument `empirical = T` on to the `mvrnorm` function if necessary when I use `fun`. So I did:

```r
dat <- fun(.sample_size = 100, .Sigma = Sigma, empirical =TRUE)

lapply(dat, cor)
#> [[1]]
#>           [,1]      [,2]
#> [1,] 1.0000000 0.3164037
#> [2,] 0.3164037 1.0000000
```

This does not seem to work however, as `empirical = T` would change the generated data such that the original `Sigma` matrix can be recovered.

If I execute the body of my function, this work:

```r
dd <- replicate(1, scale(MASS::mvrnorm(100, mu = rep(0, 2), Sigma = Sigma, empirical = TRUE)), simplify = FALSE)

lapply(dd, cor)
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]  1.0  0.3
#> [2,]  0.3  1.0
```

**Question:** What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see you actually using the optional argument in your function `fun()`.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Do you mean when invoking the function or when defining the function? I do use it when invoking dont I? `dat <- fun(.sample_size = 100, .Sigma = Sigma, empirical =TRUE)`

Comment: If the function never uses the parameter then does it matter what value you pass, or if you even pass it at all?

Comment: You need to use `...` in the function `fun`.

Comment: ok, so when i add `...` as an agrument to may top level function, I need to inserset `...` somewhere in the lower level function?

Comment: If you want to use the values inside the function, then yes.

Comment: E.g., `MASS::mvrnorm(.sample_size, mu = rep(0, ncol(.Sigma)), Sigma = .Sigma, ...)`

Comment: I added `...` to the `mvrnorm` function within the `fun` function. Still empirical=T doesn not get passed on... Have i misunderstood you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the ellipses to the function call inside the function. Otherwise, arguments passed to it are simply ignored (which sometimes is desired).

However, I believe this still doesn't work correctly, because `replicate` does not seem to support passing the ellipses. The reason probably is that it deals with expressions and not with functions. I suggest you use `lapply` directly:

```
fun <- function(.sample_size, .Sigma, .ndraws = 1, ...) {
  lapply(seq_len(.ndraws),
            function(.sample_size, .Sigma, .ndraws, ...) 
              scale(MASS::mvrnorm(.sample_size, mu = rep(0, ncol(.Sigma)), Sigma = .Sigma, ...)),
         .sample_size = .sample_size, .Sigma = .Sigma, .ndraws = .ndraws, ...)
}

Sigma <- matrix(c(1, 0.3, 0.3, 1), nrow = 2)

set.seed(42)
dat <- fun(.sample_size = 100, .Sigma = Sigma, empirical = FALSE)
dat[[1]][1:3,]
#           [,1]       [,2]
#[1,]  0.3228743  1.8240016
#[2,] -1.1732884  0.1865766
#[3,]  0.8237171 -0.2726090

set.seed(42)
dat <- fun(.sample_size = 100, .Sigma = Sigma, empirical = TRUE)
dat[[1]][1:3,]
#           [,1]       [,2]
#[1,] -0.3919629 -1.8811836
#[2,]  1.1444412 -0.4162717
#[3,] -0.7976478  0.4429600
```